Calculating the order of $\int_0^r (-\ln x)^{-\gamma} dx$ for $0< \gamma <1$.
It is expected
$$
\int_0^r \left|\frac{1}{(-\ln x)^\gamma}\right| dx\approx \frac{1}{r(-\ln r)^{\gamma + 1}}
$$
for  $0< \gamma <1$. My attempts are in the following, by a crude integral median theorem:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^r \left|\frac{1}{(-\ln x)^\gamma}\right| dx 
  &= -\int_{1/r}^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln x)^\gamma} d\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \\
  & = -\left.\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^\gamma}\right|_{1/r}^\infty+ \int_{1/r}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2(\ln x)^{\gamma+1}} \\
  & = o(r) + \frac{1}{(\ln C(r))^{\gamma+1}}\int_{1/r}^\infty x^{-2} dx \\
  & \approx \frac{1}{r(-\ln C(r))^{\gamma + 1}}
\end{align*}
Where $C(r)$ is a function related to $r$. I wonder if $\ln C(r)$ can be replaced (or dominated) by $C \ln r$.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Are you interested in $r\to 0^+$?

Yes, I would like to get an asymptotic estimate when $r \to 0^+$.

Integrating by parts $$\int_0^r 1\times(-\ln(x))^{-\gamma}dx=\left[\frac{x}{(-\ln(x))^\gamma}\right]_0^r-\gamma\int_0^{r}\frac{1}{(-\ln(x))^{\gamma+1}}dx$$
Since $x\mapsto \frac{1}{(-\ln(x))^\gamma}$ is positive, increasing on $]0;1[$, if $r\in]0;1[$ then $$\left|\int_0^{r}\frac{1}{(-\ln(x))^{\gamma+1}}dx\right|\le \frac{r}{(-\ln(r))^{\gamma+1}}=\underset{r\to 0}{o}\left(\frac{r}{(-\ln(r))^\gamma}\right)$$
Therefore $$\int_0^r\frac{1}{(-\ln(x))^\gamma}\,dx= \frac{r}{(-\ln(r))^\gamma}+\underset{r\to 0}{o}\left(\frac{r}{(-\ln(r))^\gamma}\right)$$

I recommend using a symbol for the integration variable that is different from the upper limit of integration.

Thank you for your answer! Yet this estimation seems not able to yield the relation $\approx$, just only $\le$ is concluded.

@PinaRinith The inequality shows that the integral on the RHS is negligible before $\frac{r}{(-\ln(r))^\gamma}$ as $r\to 0$. It does follow that $\int_0^r\frac{1}{(-\ln(x))^\gamma},dx\underset{r\to 0}{\sim}\frac{r}{(-\ln(r))^\gamma}$

@Ayoub Oh I got it. This is right, thanks!!

@PinaRinith You may also upvote the answer if you found it useful.

Performing the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $x=\mathrm{e}^{-t}$ and utilising the known asymptotic expansion of the generalised exponential integral, we obtain
$$
\int_{ - \ln r}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - t} }}{{t^\gamma  }}{\rm d}t}  = \frac{{E_\gamma  ( - \ln r)}}{{( - \ln r)^{\gamma  - 1} }} \sim \frac{r}{{( - \ln r)^\gamma  }}\left( {1 + \frac{\gamma }{{\ln r}} + \frac{{\gamma (\gamma  + 1)}}{{\ln ^2 r}} + \ldots } \right),
$$
as $r\to 0^+$.
You can also arrive at this result using the method you began with: by repeatedly applying integration by parts and explicitly calculating the terms at each step.

Thank you for this! The expansion of this Gamma function really helps a lot.
